# Can someone explain redis setbit command?

Tags: c, redis

```
> setbit mykey 1 1
> setbit mykey 7 1
```

When I store string value 1 and 7 into "mykey", **what was exactly stored  in redis**?
And how the getbit works inside redis?

**Does anyone try to loop the bit inside this value?** I know bitcount will give me number 2, but I also want to get the exact string value 1 and 7 from it, is it possible?

--

I doing some experiment by using erlang redis client to read the output.

```
> setbit mykey 1 1
```

erlang output:

```
<<"@">>
```

Then I delete this entry:

```
> del mykey
```

I do the same thing to offset 2 4 8, here you can see the mapping:

```
When offset is 1, the output is <<"@">>;
When offset is 2, the output is <<" ">>;
When offset is 4, the output is <<"\b">>;
When offset is 8, the output is <<0,128>>;
```

Honestly, I am more confused now.

Or someone can explain this ["bitops.c"](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/ec7f480e11e1b697c05ac40d69a6a9fca88fc439/src/bitops.c)

-- updates ---

Maybe I should mention the reason why I want to do this to make the question more clear. We all know it will be cool to use bitmap to store online users. What I am trying to do is get the exactly user id who is online from what redis stored.

**Just finished a [quick version](https://github.com/JoshuaChi/extract-offsets-from-redis-bitmap) to extract offsets from redis. Please feel free to improve it.**

Comment: e.g. if I do "get mykey", I get "A\X80", what's this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As its name implies, `SETBIT` allows you to perform bit operations - namely set a given bit to 0 or 1, at a given bit offset, for a given key.

What is important to understand is that the result not always includes only printable characters. This is why Redis uses a [custom function `sdscatrepr`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/320fa02/deps/hiredis/sds.c#L553-L576) to format the CLI output:

> Append to the sds string "s" an escaped string representation where all the non-printable characters (tested with isprint()) are turned into escapes in the form "\n\r\a...." or "\x".

That being said let's start with a simple example. If you consider the hex number `0x7F` (= 127) its binary representation on 8-bit is:

```
pos: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
bit: 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
     ^             ^
     |             |
     MSB           LSB
```

You can typically use `SETBIT` to store this value, keeping in mind that offset `0` is `MSB` and offset 7 is `LSB`:

```
redis> SETBIT myval 0 0
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 1 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 2 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 3 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 4 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 5 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 6 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 7 1
(integer) 0
```

The get your value to inspect if:

```
redis> GET myval
"\x7f"
```

Now what happens with multi bytes? Let's say you want to store `0x52` (= 82) which corresponds to character `R` in ASCII. The 8-bit representation is `01010010` with bit positions `(8, 9, ..., 15)` since we want it to be stored right after the first value:

```
redis> SETBIT myval 8 0
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 9 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 10 0
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 11 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 12 0
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 13 0
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 14 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT myval 15 0
(integer) 0
```

And you get:

```
redis> GET myval
"\x7fR"
```

Here Redis CLI is able to represent the printable character `R`.

> When I store string value 1 and 7 into "mykey"

It corresponds to `01000001` which is equal to 65 and `0x41` in hex. It corresponds to ASCII character `A`. So doing:

```
redis> SETBIT mykey 1 1
(integer) 0
redis> SETBIT mykey 7 1
(integer) 0
```

Gives:

```
redis> GET mykey
"A"
```

> how the getbit works inside redis?

It simply returns the value of the bit at the given position. Here:

```
redis> GETBIT mykey 1
(integer) 1
```

But bit 0 has not been set (it is 0 by default) thus:

```
redis> GETBIT mykey 0
(integer) 0
```

Comment: Thanks for those information, I am wondering is it possible to get the  string values(e.g. 1 and 7) by parsing ASCII characters(e.g. "A") which get from redis? I know redis doesn't provide such kind of functions. It will be cool if someone can give some hints.

Comment: What do you mean by string values? (1 and 7 are bit offsets here). That said: you are free to manipulate Redis bulk replies the way you want (this is no more than a byte array) - see http://redis.io/topics/protocol.

Comment: Sorry, according to [redis document](http://redis.io/commands/setbit), _"Sets or clears the bit at offset in the string value stored at key."_ What I mean is that is it possible to get the offset from the string value. I am still trying to parse it in Erlang. e.g.  If we do `setbit mykey 1 1` and `setbit mykey 2 1`, we get the output `<<96>>`;  If we do `setbit mykey 1 1`, `setbit mykey 8 1` and `setbit mykey 16 1`, we get the output `<<64, 128, 128>>`. So what I am trying to do is parse the output and get the offsets out of it. (Sorry, the formats looked weird here.)

Comment: Since this is an Erlang topic this time about [bitstrings](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) you should open a new dedicated question.

Comment: No need now, thanks. I have attached the github repository link in ticket description. So anyone who is interested can take a look of my solution.

Comment: @deltheil If the default value of any offset is bit 0, why we have to `SETBIT key offset 0`?

Answer (score 1):

u can see the exactly details in http://redis.io

**GETBIT key offset**

Returns the bit value at offset in the string value stored at key.
When offset is beyond the string length, the string is assumed to be a contiguous space with 0 bits. When key does not exist it is assumed to be an empty string, so offset is always out of range and the value is also assumed to be a contiguous space with 0 bits.

examples:

```
redis> SETBIT mykey 7 1
(integer) 0
redis> GETBIT mykey 0
(integer) 0
redis> GETBIT mykey 7
(integer) 1
redis> GETBIT mykey 100
(integer) 0
redis>
```

Comment: thanks, I know how to use it. I want to know what exactly stored in redis. e.g. if I do "get mykey", I get "A\X80", what's this?

Comment: @jaylzhang can you please give your own examples and not use what is already easily available in redis docs? Please explain the logic setbit and getbit with your understanding.

Comment: @Nik  Sorry. I think the example is enough, so didn't use my own example yesterday. Now, i think i am no need to show my own example, because another reply is more authoritative.